# Can I run 2x10 XT Shifters on a flatbar road bike with 105 10 speed STI components?

Tags: derailleur, parts, shifter, drivetrain

I want to run 2x10 XT shifters on a flatbar but still want use the 10 speed 105 components of the road bike would there be any problems?

Comment: in its current form I can only guess what you are asking for exactly. Maybe you want to expand your question a bit to explain in more detail what your question is about.

Comment: Can I use XT 10x2 shifters with the 105 groupset as I wish to covert my roadie to a flatbar roadie

Comment: As stated in the answer below, it is possible to run 105 components on a flat bar with the right choice of components (the Trek 7.5 and 7.7 among others do this). The bigger issue in the conversion is the geometry - bolting on a flatbar onto something designed for drops will totally change the riding position, so the stem length and diameter have to be changed in the hope that you can get a position which fits nicely enough for you (which isn't always possible). It is typically better to just get a flatbar road bike to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for replacing your STI shifters for use with flat bars (but not the XT shifters for the reasons in the comments):

You can use Shimano SL-R780 Flat Bar Shifter 2x10SP shifters with 105 components on flat bars.

http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/au/index/products/road/flat_handlebar.html

You could get some 10 speed bar end or downtube shifters and use those with some paul's components thumbies.

http://www.paulcomp.com/thumbies.html

You could get 10 speed bar end or downtube shifters and mount them on the downtube or stem with some problem solvers downtube shifter mounts.

http://problemsolversbike.com/products/downtube_shifter_mount1

Comment: You could probably get a pretty penny for your old shifters as well, you can probably fund the replacement parts fully if your old 105 STI shifters are in good condition.

Comment: Note that the XT 10x2 won't work out of the box since the cable pull for the front derailleur is different between shimano mountain and shimano road, so you do need the flat bar shifter set (which is a bit more expensive) or rig up some pulleys to get the cable pull right (which is not recommended).